# proxy and htmlagilitypack issues

Tags: c#, vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have been trying to use the htmlagilitypack through a proxy and I see that I get some unpredictable behavior.

How do you add credentials to htmlagilitypack so that it will be able to scrape web pages  through a proxy?

Comment: Use `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` to download the page and then load the string to HAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I usually do:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
...
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)) {
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader.BaseStream);

    //Use (or return) the HtmlDocument 'doc' here.
}
```

You could encapsulate this code on a *method* that given a url, returns a `HtmlDocument` object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question already answered here[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099538/using-a-proxy-with-htmlagilitypack)

You use it as below in your code.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6";
var doc = web.Load(string url, string proxyHost, int proxyPort, string yourUserId, string yourPassword);
```