# using a proxy with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I searched this question but didn't find anything that I was looking for, basically I want to use a proxy with htmlagilitypack, I had the code to do it before but lost it, here is the code I have so far, which is working. but I timed my self out on a program I was making and need to enable proxies.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        string raw = "http://www.google.com";
        HtmlWeb webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        webGet.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6";
        var document = webGet.Load(raw);


    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Within our corporate setup, adding this to app.config works for me without the need for any code changes

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```

Comment: I wish the guy who asked would mark this as answer! Simple and resolved with glory for me! Thanks

Comment: OMG!!! I have been searching solution to my problem for over 2 MONTHS!!!! THIS IS JUST SUPER AWESOME!!!

Answer (score 6):

Use an overload of `HtmlWeb.Load()` that uses proxies.  There are two overload signatures:

```
HtmlDocument Load(string url, string method, WebProxy proxy, NetworkCredential credentials);
HtmlDocument Load(string url, string proxyHost, int proxyPort, string userId, string password);
```

I don't have any first-hand experience using proxies in my code but I'd expect this to work.

Comment: the webclient one seems to be working the best, although the ip and port needs to be on the same line because the proxies will be loaded in from a text file and there is not a separate input for proxy and port in my program.

Comment: Either parse out the host and ports or use the overload that accepts a `WebProxy` object and create the instance using the overload that accepts a string, [`WebProxy(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2tt59d8.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

HtmlAgilityPack doesn't download data from url. Use a class to download the page that supports Proxy.

For example

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(host,port);
var page = wc.DownloadString(url);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you read something like `11.22.33.44:5678`  from text file, it is also possible to create the proxy as

```
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("11.22.33.44:5678");
```

Comment: so the parsing is still the same process after that such as. `var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='forumtitle']");`