# SelectNode always Null in Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I try to use HtmlAgilityPack to get value of tag div, But my result is always null. I don't know why it don't get value.

this code:

```
HtmlWeb website = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument rootDocument = website.Load("http://blogviet.com.vn");
var value= rootDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
if (value!= null)
{
    foreach (var tag in value)
    {
        if (tag.Attributes["class"] != null)
        {
            label2.Text += tag.Attributes["class"].Value + "\n";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    label2.Text = "null";
}
```

Comment: Your code works... try a friendly URL... Look at blogviet.com.vn robots file... http://blogviet.com.vn/robots.txt ... they don't want anyone looking at their site. Have a fiddle... https://dotnetfiddle.net/x2uCd1 you could most likely use a proxy and fake the user-agent etc in order to try to bypass this, but it's not nice to... and they will likely ban your IP address once they detect it.

Comment: Can u say me how to create a proxy and fake the user-agent?

Comment: Google is your friend... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099538/using-a-proxy-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: I did "using a proxy with htmlagilitypack". But I can't get html of website. Do You can write program example to get anything text or value, href  from this website?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Descendants`

```
var divNodes = rootDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");
var classNames =  divNodes.Select(d => d.GetAttributeValue("class","").Where(x => x != "");
label2.Text  = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, classNames);
```

Comment: I try Descendants, but result is null. My code apply for different website  it can get value. I think website http://blogviet.com.vn , it brattle HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @toan is your website loaded correctly? have you checked via debugger?

Comment: test your code. I try and result null. It don't get not only tag div  but also  the body or meta. It do not result.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code.the problem is your website, I'm asking if you check the document node in the debugger