# HtmlAgilityPack LoadFromBrowser with Proxy

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Is there a way to specify a proxy for the method "LoadFromBrowser"? The "Load()" has overload for supplying the information.

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.LoadFromBrowser(url);
```

I can not use "Load()" because will be the default source and not the active one. Things like Ajax will not be called. It is closer to a real browser. Otherwise, that "LoadFromBrowser()" would not make sense as there is already the same "Load()" signature.

See: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using a proxy with htmlagilitypack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099538/using-a-proxy-with-htmlagilitypack)

Comment: Consider using AngleSharp instead of HAP.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the answer: [using proxy with htmlagilitypack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099538/using-a-proxy-with-htmlagilitypack)

First you create an object of type **WebProxy(string)** and then you just use the overload of **HtmlWeb.Load()**.

Comment: "LoadFromBrowser" does more than just loading the default source ("View Source" from the browser) as the "Load" methods does. Will do things like Ajax, etc.